# Making animation with mathematica for sphere

Tags: graphics, graphics3d, animation

How to make animation in mathematica for 3D sphere which randomly its radius increase and decreases?
Thanks

Comment: Please include Mathematica code for what you have tried out so far. Thanks.

Comment: If you do it "randomly" it would be visually quite annoying. `Animate[Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, r], PlotRange -> 1.1, Boxed -> False], {r, 1/2, 1, 1/100}, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- One way

The code

```
Animate[SphericalPlot3D[xx, θ, φ, PlotRange -> 11, 
  Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> {Red, Thick}], {xx, 1, 10}, 
 AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

> [image: gif2]

- Another way

The code

```
Animate[RegionPlot3D[
  Norm[{x, y, z}] <= xx, {x, -10, 10}, {y, -10, 10}, {z, -10, 
   10}], {xx, 1, 10}, AnimationDirection -> ForwardBackward]
```

> [image: gif]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @aminbk you're very welcome :) Please keep in mind that these are only two ways and there are more. I suggest you look up the commands on the docs and from there you will be able to find related commands to find out more ways to do it!